# MacBookPro5,5 Broadcom STA Wireless Driver fails to install (ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom, macbook-pro

It says "Sorry, installation of this driver failed"
Here's the log:

```
2014-01-09 12:50:31,831 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2014-01-09 12:50:36,216 WARNING: modinfo for module wl failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module wl

2014-01-09 12:50:36,217 WARNING: /sys/module/wl/drivers does not exist, cannot rebind wl driver
2014-01-09 12:50:36,258 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
```

Comment: What is the method you used to install? Additional Drivers, apt-get or compiled from source? Please edit your question to add this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest Ubuntu version 13.10 and you will have no driver problems:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=32&distro=desktop&status=zeroc

If you have 4 gigs of ram or more download:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=64&distro=desktop&status=zeroc

Do a backup of your files, clean install and you will have your Macbook Pro working 100% fine out of the box.